# Why $(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)/(\mathbb Z\times{=})$ is not homeomorphic to $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)\times(\mathbb Q/{=})$?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, products, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathbb Q$ be the set of rationals with induced euclidian topology, let $\sim_1$ be the relation on $\mathbb Q$ which identifies all the integers, and let $\sim_2$ be the identity relation on $\mathbb Q$.

Why the spaces $(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)/({\sim}_1\times{\sim}_2)$ and $(\mathbb Q/{\sim}_1)\times(\mathbb Q/{\sim}_2)$ are not homeomorphic?

Comment: What reason do you think they aren't homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $X=(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})/({\sim}_1\times{\sim}_2)$ is a quotient of a sequential space and hence sequential, so it suffices to show the space $Y=(\mathbb{Q}/{\sim}_1)\times(\mathbb{Q}/{\sim}_2)$ is not sequential.  Fix a sequence $(\alpha_n)$ of positive irrational numbers converging to $0$.  For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, choose a sequence of points $(x_{mn},y_{mn})\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ converging to $(n,\alpha_n)$ such that $0<|x_{mn}-n|<1/2$ for all $m$.  Let $A=\{(x_{mn},y_{mn}):m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, thought of as a subset of $Y$ in the obvious way.  Then I claim that $A$ is sequentially closed but not closed in $Y$, so $Y$ is not sequential.

First, $A$ is not closed: it is easy to see that any open neighborhood of the point $(\mathbb{Z},0)$ in $Y$ must intersect $A$ because $\alpha_n$ converges to $0$ (here $\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the equivalence class of the integers as an element of $\mathbb{Q}/{\sim}_1$).  Since $(\mathbb{Z},0)\not\in A$, $A$ is not closed.

Second, $A$ is sequentially closed.  In fact, I claim that no sequence of distinct elements of $A$ converges in $Y$.  Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence of distinct elements of $A$; then there are integers $m_k$ and $n_k$ such that $a_k=(x_{m_kn_k},y_{m_kn_k})$ for each $k$.  Suppose that $(a_k)$ converges; then $(x_{m_kn_k})$ must converge in $\mathbb{Q}/{\sim}_1$ and $(y_{m_kn_k})$ must converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since the numbers $\alpha_n$ are irrational, the only way $(y_{m_kn_k})$ can converge is if the sequence $(n_k)$ is unbounded.  Passing to a subsequence, we may assume that the integers $n_k$ are all distinct.  But now I claim the sequence $(x_{m_kn_k})$ cannot converge.  Indeed, it is clear that the only point it could possibly converge to is $\mathbb{Z}$.  For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $U_n\subset\mathbb{Q}$ be an interval around $n$ small enough to not contain $x_{m_kn_k}$ for any $k$ such that $n_k=n$ (there is at most one such $k$).  Then the image of $U=\bigcup U_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}/{\sim}_1$ is a neighborhood of $\mathbb{Z}$ that does not contain any $x_{m_kn_k}$.  Thus $(x_{m_kn_k})$ cannot converge to $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence cannot converge at all.  This is a contradiction, so $(a_k)$ cannot converge.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer) Do you know a simpler example of non-homeomorphic spaces $(X\times Y)/({\sim}_1\times{\sim}_2)$ and $(X/{\sim}_1)\times(Y/{\sim}_2)$?

Comment: Not really.  You can examine this argument and see that you can make $X$ and $Y$ a bit smaller than $\mathbb{Q}$ (you only need the integers and the points $x_{mn}$ in $X$ and $0$ and the points $y_{mn}$ in $Y$).  But I don't know of any example where the proof is essentially less complicated than this.  Note that if you only want to know that the obvious bijection is not a homeomorphism (rather than that there is no homemomorphism at all), you can skip my final paragraph and instead prove that $A$ is closed in $(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})/({\sim}_1\times{\sim}_2)$, which is slightly easier.

Comment: Note that a major obstacle to a simpler example is that if you demand that $\sim_2$ is the trivial equivalence relation, there can be no such example with $Y$ locally compact (a product of a quotient map with a locally compact space is still a quotient map).

Comment: I am sorry, I have not specified general task properly. It is well-known that quotient space of topological product by the product of open equivalence relations on factors is homeomorphic to the product of corresponding quotient spaces. But the fact does not hold for the closed relations even for two factors. I try to find a relatively simple example for closed relations and two factors. The spaces above are mentioned in several books as "standard" example for this.

Comment: By "simple example" I mean one using major topological properties like first and second countability, Lindelof property, compactness, separability, separation axioms $T_0$, $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$, $T_4$, metrizability, connectedness and path connectedness.